# Perl Comparison with Bot::BasicBot( testing Equality )

Tags: perl, comparison, bots

I've figured it out it appears that I was testing each key individually and thats why it kept saying i wasn't in the Operators list.

trick was to move the else statement out of foreach and to change it to a if statement.

then a rather nasty hack inside the test for not equal

original:

```
if($config->{'OP'}[$key] ne $message->{who})
```

new:

```
if($config->{'OP'}[$key-1] ne $message->{who})
```

final complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package kbot;
use base qw(Bot::BasicBot);
use YAML;
use Data::Dumper;


my $bot = kbot->new(
                server => 'irc.saurik.com',
                channels => ['#spam','#kbot'],
                nick => 'kbot',);


sub reload{
        system("perl kbot.pl");
}


sub said {
        my ($self, $message) = @_;
        my $config = YAML::LoadFile('kelbot.yml');
        if($message->{body} =~ 'reload'){
                reload();
        }

        if($message->{body} =~ 'opme'){
                  foreach $::key (keys $config->{OP}){
                        print $config->{OP}[$::key],"\n";
                        if($config->{OP}[$::key] eq $message->{who}){
                                $bot->mode($message->{channel}.' +o '.$message->{who});

                        } #end of if op
                  } #end of foreach
                  if($config->{OP}[$::key-1] ne $message->{who}){
                                $bot->say( channel => $message->{channel},
                                body => 'You aren\'t in the Operators list.',
                                address => $message->{who},
                                 );
                } #end of optest
        } #end of opme

} #end of said

sub chanjoin {
        my ($self, $message) = @_;
        return 'kbot now online!';
}

$bot->run();
```

Comment: On the line `if($message->{body} =~ 'opme'){` do you really mean that the body simply contains the substring 'opme' or do you want the body to equal 'opme'. If you want contains replace the quotes with slashes (`=~ /opme/`) which makes your intend much clearer. If you mean equals then write `eq 'opme'`. Mixing the binding operator and the string leaves it open to doubt IMHO.

Comment: before i was regex'ing but just getting use to using it though before it was /\bWORD\b/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are much better ways of doing that in perl than trying to create a c-esque loop.  From the code it looks like `$config->{'OP'}` is an array, but I'm a bit confused by your use of the array subscript (`[]`) and `keys` on it at the same time. If it is an array then just use `grep`

```
if (grep { $_ eq $message->{who} } @{ $config->{OP} }) {
    $bot->mode("$message->{channel} +o $message->{who}");
} else {
    $bot->say(channel => $message->{channel},
              body => q{You aren't in the Operators list.},
              address => $message->{who});
}
```

This code would completely replace your foreach loop. The `grep` command is the thing that loops over the entire list and finds whether `$message->{who}` appears in it. Since that is done so easily in a single statement, the if condition about what to do in the case of it appearing or not is very straightforward.

Comment: Wow that simplified it so much thanks :D although if you refer to my original post i found a rather nasty hack :P +1'ed you and accepted though :D. $config is a YAML format file that is loaded {OP} is a hash(or was now its an array) $key is just to iterate over it.